# Compare UUID fields in a Mongo query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to write a MongoDB query in which I can compare the values of UUID fields.

I am able to easily compare *string* fields which a command something like this:

```
db.T.find({ $where: function() {return this.foo === this.bar}})
```

However the same function doesn't seem to work when comparing UUIDs. Does the $where method only work with strings? And if so is there another command I can use to compare other types of field?

To be more precise, I am using Mongo UUIDs stored as type "Binary - UUID".

Answer (score 4):

If you need to use the UUID in the "$where" function, you can transform the UUID into a string.
For example, if the "foo" and "bar" fields are UUID objects:

```
db.T.find({ $where: function() {return this.foo.toString() === this.bar.toString()}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly I don't understand why you want to use $where.It has some disadvantages cant use indexes, cant be applied on nested fields etc.. Plese see below link [https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/]

You can search for uuid :
db.T.find({ "foo" : UUID("4415999c-53f3-48b3-be17-65af08c86980") });

Comment: Yeah probably because you didn't read my question ;)
I need to compare 2 fields with each, not match one with a constant string as in your example.

Comment: my bad, atleast now i see you have solution thats great!